# Inserting name with special characters with php in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apostrophe

I'm trying to insert some names with special characters, such as an apostrophe, into a mysql database using php. For example:

```
INSERT INTO PLAYERS VALUES('{$players[$n][1]}','$nom_team');
```

where `$players` is an array that contains names as `N'Zogbia`, `N'Diaye`, etc. However, this results in an error.

I have tried using the addslashes function:

```
$players[$n][1] = addslashes( $players[$n][1] );
```

but this doesn't work correctly. What gets saved in the database is `N\'Zogbia`, or sometimes `N\\\\\\\\\\'Diaye`.

I have run out of ideas to fix the problem. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: The idea is that if you use `addslashes()` to escape the value for MySQL, that you would then use `stripslashes()` when reading the values back out at some point.

Comment: You most likely have `magic_quotes` enabled.

Comment: You should also look at using prepared statements and placeholders, so you can avoid having to use `addslashes` and `stripslashes` completely.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible cases

1. You have magic quotes on. [Turn them off.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php)
2. Some sort of **Sanitize Them All** function run on all your input data. Get rid of it.

Comment: It doesnt work, for any reason the script include multiple slashes in the names so when i get back the data from mysql stripslash just remove one slash so the others are still there...

Answer (score -1):

You can use prepared statement.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$city = "N'Zogbia";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $district);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    printf("%s is in district %s\n", $city, $district);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```